# Javascript: Why my function isn't called by onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm writing a form validation using Jscript,

But I don't know why I just can't even call a simple alert function by onclick.

Here's part of my code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Check</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function displaymessage()
{
alert("Hello World!");
}
</script></head>
```

...

```
<form name="checkout" id="checkout" method="post" action="1.php">
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td>*Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="40"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>*Phone</td>
<td><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" size="40"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>*Address</td>
<td><textarea rows="4" cols="40" name="address"></textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="return displaymessage()" />
</form>
</html>
```

I suppose the button should be a submit button

`<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit"onclick="return validate_form()"/>`

But during my testing, even a simple "Click me!" button doesn't work... Will there be anyone who countered kind of question like that before?

Comment: `onclick` attribute is together value..without a space

Comment: oh crap.. if i remove my validate_form() function then the button works again

Comment: does it means my `validate_form()` function having some problems?

Comment: If the function got some errors, the form won't be submitted.

Comment: you can validate the form in `submit` event

Comment: finally I press F12 on chrome and see the console tag, i find`validate_form()` occurs syntax error so the script is not loaded. how silly I am..

Comment: by the way I like the idea given by LJ, it is impressive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample snippet to play around with.

The logic should be:

The function `validate_form` should return `true` if validation is successful; otherwise `false`. If the return value is `true` the `form` would be submitted.

```js
var validate_form = function() {

  var allGood = true; // all good if validation is successful. 

  // check if name is valid
  allGood = document.querySelector("#name").value.length > 0;

  // do other validataions... and return whether all is good
  if (allGood) {
    console.log("We are okay to proceed");
  } else {
    console.log("Please make sure the form inputs are entered to proceed");
  }
  return allGood;
}

var action_form = function() {
  // validate form..
  var isFormValid = validate_form();

  // do other actions..
  // ... 

  // submit the form...
  if (isFormValid) {
    console.log("submitting the form...");
    document.querySelector("#checkout").submit();
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="checkout" id="checkout" method="post" action="https://google.com">
  <table align="center">
    <tr>
      <td>*Name</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="40" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>*Phone</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" size="40" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>*Address</td>
      <td>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="40" name="address"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <!-- <input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="action_form()" /> or the below -->
  <input type="submit" value="Click me!" onclick="return validate_form()" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a real button like :

`<button type="submit" onclick="onSubmitClick()">Submit</button>`.

You can also add `onsubmit="onSubmit()"` into the form tag.

```js
function onSubmitClick() {
  alert('Submitted');
}
```

```html
<!-- Action on the button -->
<form>
  <table align="center">
    <tr>
      <td>*Name</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="40" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>*Phone</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" size="40" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>*Address</td>
      <td>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="40" name="address"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="submit" onclick="onSubmitClick()">Submit</button>
</form>

<!-- Action on the form (if multiple submit, it's better) -->
<form onsubmit="onSubmitClick()">
  <table align="center">
    <tr>
      <td>*Name</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="40" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>*Phone</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" size="40" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>*Address</td>
      <td>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="40" name="address"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked and it works fine. You don't need the return. You aren't returning a value, you are running an alert.

Someone has mentioned onSubmitClick, onClick will work just as well, though technically you submitting a form when you click it. onSubmitClick wouldn't work with other objects.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Check</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function displaymessage()
        {
            alert("Hello World!");
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="checkout" id="checkout" method="post" action="1.php">
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>*Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="40" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>*Phone</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" size="40" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>*Address</td>
                <td><textarea rows="4" cols="40" name="address"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="displaymessage();" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to validate the form before the submit it, something like this..

```
<input id="mybtn" type="button" value="Click me!" />
```

JS:

```
var form = document.getElementById("checkout");
document.getElementById("mybtn").addEventListener("click", function () {
  if ( validate_form() )
      form.submit();
  else 
      alert("Name is empty");
});

function validate_form(){
   var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
   if ( !value )
       return false;
   else 
       return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `return` statment

```
function displaymessage(){
    alert("Hello World!");
}

<input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="displaymessage()" />
```

see the [onclick event example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)